# Powers of two in an infinite sequence of arbitrary integers

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing

I'm not sure how to ask this properly and I haven't seen this problem anywhere yet, but I'm still interested if this can be (dis)proven or not.

Consider a finite sequence of the numbers 1, 2, 4, and 8:

```
148218
```

It is easy to split this sequence into integer powers of two:

```
1 4 8 2 1 8
```

It's possible to do this with longer substrings and higher powers as well, here's a simple example:

```
142816321128
```

Can be split into:

```
1 4 2 8 16 32 1 128
```

Can a similar split be done on any given infinite sequence of numbers (not starting with 0)? We know that all 10 digits occur somewhere in the powers of two. Another example, we have an infinite sequence of numbers which starts like so:

```
17 ...
```

Which is not a power of two, but the sequence might continue in this way:

```
17179869184 ...
```

And that's $2^{34}$. But maybe the sequence continues in a different way – can we always find a power of two that can match the sequence?

I suppose that another way to ask the same question is, given any sequence of digits, is it possible to find a power of two that starts with these digits?

Comment: You seem to ask two different questions. One is whether any sequence of integers may be split into subsequences that represent powers of $2$. That is not true, take $3333\ldots$ as a counterexample. Your other question, given a finite sequence of digits, whether there is a power of $2$ that begins with that sequence, has the answer is yes. The proof boils down to the fact that $\log_{10}2$ is irrational.

Comment: @Arthur Thanks! I guess I was mostly thinking about uniformly-distributed infinite sequences, not particular counter-examples. How can one prove the second 'question' then? I assume the irrationality of $\log_{10}2$ means it's decimal expansion will contain any given sequence of digits … But how do you get from that to 'there is a power of two starting with any given sequence of digits'?

Comment: No, it has not been proved that the decimal expansion of $\log_{10}2$ contains every finite sequence of digits. But it is irrational, and it's known that if $\alpha$ is irrational then the fractional parts of the numbers $\alpha,2\alpha,3\alpha,\dots$ are dense (indeed, uniformly distributed) in $[0.1)$.